# No c Puede Convertir un Objeto system Drawing en System Byte

Tags: visual

Tengo un Eveto CellPainting en la grilla el problema es que cuando agrego un producto con Foto que no esta Guradado anteriormente en la BD me nada el horror "No se puede convertir el objeto de System Drawing a system byte"
Soy novato en esto espero su gran ayuda Nota: Como es un sistema de servicios los agrego al vuelo con su imagen...Esta pasa la imagen pero al posicionarse en la fila que se agrego me manda dicho error." ya hice 3 y van 0 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).